# Convert string from ftp to json

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a file from an Ftp server that looks like :

```
var a = "some text"
var b= new Array(2,6,9,11,11,13,13,12,10,6,4,3)
var c=890
var d= 3
var e=new Array(d)
e[0]=new Array(13300,95000,2350000,14000000)
e[1]=new Array(13300,95000,2350000,14000000)
e[2]=new Array(11100,80000,1950000,11500000)

var f= new Array(d)
f[0]=new Array("x","y",140,1,"z",2,null,null,130,null,7,0,1,1000,null)
f[0][6]=new Array("String 1","String 2")
f[0][7]=new Array(1,1)
f[0][9]=new Array(7350,7350)
f[0][16]=1
f[1]=new Array("x","y",140,1,"z",2,null,null,130,null,7,0,1,1000,null)
f[1][6]=new Array("String 1","String 2")
f[1][7]=new Array(1,1)
f[1][9]=new Array(7350,7350)
f[1][16]=1
f[2]=new Array("x","y",140,1,"z",2,null,null,130,null,7,0,1,1000,null)
f[2][6]=new Array("String 1","String 2")
f[2][7]=new Array(2,2)
f[2][9]=new Array(5880,6370)
f[2][16]=1
var g="foo"
var h= new Array(3)
var i= new Array(3)
h[0] = "k,l ,m ,n ,o ,p ,q"
i[0] = "r,s,t,u,v,w"
```

it would like to convert it to json, so that i can pass it arround in my app (MVC) 
something like

```
{
    "MyData"
        "a" : "some text"
        "b" : [2,6,9,11,11,13,13,12,10,6,4,3]
        "c" : 890
        "d" : 3
        "e" : ["13300,95000,2350000,14000000","...","..."]
        ....
        ....
}
```

Is there anyway i can achieve this (use json.net or other librarie)?
Thx in advance

Comment: That Ftp file looks like a script that needs to be interpreted/executed.  Is it in some language?

Comment: if it is, its not something i know. Most closely to javascript i suppose

Comment: json.net is a great library for converting your objects to/from  json.  When treated as an object, your ftp file is just an array of chars.  The contents of your file do not appear to be related to json in any way.  I think you want to interpret/execute this file to extract the values of all of the variables when the script completes.  Json.net won't extract the values.  I think your next step is to determine the origin of this file.